# Android status bar becomes white when using toolbar in Linear layout

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout

When I try to use the toolbar with LinearLayout the activities status bar becomes white but when i replace the LinearLayout with CoordinatorLayout it shows up properly.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is using Linear layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Is it supposed to be used in this way because When I used it earlier before CoordinatorLayout it was working?

Below is the screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place this line of code in your values-v21/styles.xml, to enable this on Lollipop:

```
<resources>
 <!-- Base application theme. -->
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/color_primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/color_secondary</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/color_accent</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/color_primary</item>
 </style>
</resources>
```

This work from Lollipop(API 21)

Comment: I did not check the styles properly. By default the status bar color was set to transparent. Thanks